# Alignment issues with spans

Tags: html, css

Why does the followin HTML yield the *asdf aligned to the bottom of its parent div?

```
<html>
<style>
.tag_editor
{
float: none;
width: 400px;
height: 33px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #B2B2B2;
border-width: thin;
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
<p>
<span class="tag_editor" style="">
<span>
<input type='text' style='width: 40px'/>
</span>
</span>
<span style="">*asdf</span>
</p>
</html>
```

Sorry about the bad jsfiddle links, I havn't tried to share it before:

http://jsfiddle.net/IdeaHat/y7tLZ/

Comment: If your input is the same width as the parent, it will push everything else down. Naming the class "div" for a span is confusing...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @helion3 Yeah sorry about that have been playing around with it, i'll change it. However, it still "pushes everything down" if width is set to 40 for the text box.

Comment: @Karl right now, I'm trying to get that text to be centered. I did it with margins a while ago, but now this weird lower align happened.

Comment: @Paulie_D http://jsfiddle.net/IdeaHat/62AZh/

Comment: Your HTML is not valid! Please fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the default value of the `vertical-align` property on your span tag is not set, so it is defaulting to "baseline".

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code snippet.

HTML

```
 <p>
    <span class="tag_editor" style="">
    <span>
     <input type='text' style='width: 40px'/>
    </span>
    </span>
    <span style="vertical-align:top;">*asdf</span>
    </p>
```

CSS

```
.tag_editor
    {
    float: none;
    width: 400px;
    height: 33px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #B2B2B2;
    border-width: thin;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
```

[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gK8se/1/)

Comment: Hey, that does work. Makes sense with the default verical-align==basline

Comment: The question was "why does this happen" and not "how do I top align it"!

Comment: I do not have exact idea but as per my experience when we set height in textbox and button at that time one of them increase the height at the bottom/one side and another one increase the height at the top and bottom side both. In short all controls are not increases their height in same manner. That's why..